# reading a log file with different sequences using shell script

Tags: linux, string, shell

I'm a starter with shell scripting and I wanted to ask you a question about reading data from a log file. the file is really long and includes few steps of calculation convergence.

> step 1
>
> ...
>
> converged
>
> final energy : 1000000
>
> step 2
>
> ...
>
> converged
>
> final energy : 10000
>
> ...
>
> structure optimized
>
> final energy: 100000

what I need to do is to first find if the structure is finally optimized if so the read the final energy and some other data. In mathematica I could find the position of structure optimized and do a search from there is the same thing possible in shell?
I'm a starter please list all the commands I need to use

Comment: Which shell, specifically? The capabilities available in POSIX sh are very different from those in ksh or bash.

Comment: Also, you'll need to make your question more explicit / clear before it's answerable. Is "final energy" a literal string? A placeholder for a number you want to extract? Something else?

Comment: I'd also seriously consider implementing this in awk rather than in shell.

Comment: as I said I'm rather new 
final energy would be the keyword which in front of it is a value.
I need to write a script which would run on linux cluster, wouldn't really mind which shell.

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi, here is a tip. Your question is fine until you get to **please list all the commands I need to use**. This will draw a lot of unfavorable attention. Why? S.O. is a programming site and we expect those seeking help to put in the effort to figure out exactly what they are stuck on. This isn't a "do it for me." site. That said, there is nothing wrong with asking for help -- that's why we're here. Just don't draw a target on your back by asking for someone to do it for you.

Comment: I understand what you say, what I had in mind was more like a list of keywords commands which I can use as I was reading other topics I was lost how to do it in shell. thanks

Comment: The new accepted answer is a fine answer, but an awk script is not a shell script (as awk is not a shell). If you wanted awk, you could have asked for it.

Comment: (Similarly, a "shell script" that runs `python -c '<python script>'` is really a Python script with a tiny shell wrapper, as opposed to a shell script per se).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in awk version

```
awk '{if($0=="structure optimized")i=1;if(($0~/final energy/) && (i==1)){print "Found optimized "$0;i=0}}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

This might look something like the following:

```
optimized=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    "structure optimized")
      optimized=1
      continue
      ;;
    "final energy")
      [ "$optimized" = 1 ] || continue
      echo "Found final energy after structure optimized"
      ;;
  esac
done <input.log
```

If when you put `final energy` in your sample file, you really mean something like:

```
final energy: 10000
```

...then you might change the relevant clause to:

```
"final energy: "*)
  [ "$optimized" = 1 ] || continue
  final_energy=${line#*:}
  echo "Found optimized final energy: $final_energy"
  ;;
```

...but without a detailed and precise specification, how's anyone to know exactly what you mean?